# Non-Admin registration of ActiveX Controls

Tags: deployment, internet-explorer-8, activex, atl, registration

according to [Non-Admin ActiveX Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd433049%28VS.85%29.aspx#_code), it is possible to register activeX under current user (that will not require admin right during the installation).
I have crated ATL project (VS2008, native)  and added some ATL Control that does nothing.

I created an inf file:

```
    [version]
    signature="$CHICAGO$"
    AdvancedINF=2.0

[Add.Code]
     Batman.dll=Batman.dll

[Deployment]
    InstallScope=user

[Batman.dll]
    file-win32-x86=thiscab
    clsid={2C10EC82-2BF3-4ED5-8AFC-E5146C672B3D}
    FileVersion=1,0,0,1
    RegisterServer=yes
```

Add both the dll and inf into CAB and signed it.
I load an ActiveX from simple html page

```
<OBJECT ID="sampleControl" CLASSID="CLSID:2C10EC82-2BF3-4ED5-8AFC-E5146C672B3D" CODEBASE="Batman.cab#Version=1,0,0,1"></OBJECT>
```

And it does not register it under current user anyhow.

I case I specify InstallScope=machine there is not problem the activeX is loaded.

Any idea what should be done ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I encounter the same problem, but the strangest part is, it's ok with Apache Server while not with Tomcat Server.

Finally, I found it also related to Web Server setting.

Your Web Server **MUST** support correct mime type mapping. If you test with Tomcat, add following to web.xml:

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>cab</extension>
    <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-cab-compressed</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

With the version of ATL that comes with VS2008, you can do this with:

AtlSetPerUserRegistration(TRUE);

Call that in DllRegisterServer and DllUnregisterServer at the beginning.  If you need to do this in vs2005 or earlier, you'll have to use a scarier hack.

An example of a class that takes care of both methods for you (depending on the vs ver) is here:
https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/src/ActiveXCore/axutil.cpp

and the example usage here:
https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/src/PluginAuto/Win/FireBreathWin.cpp

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this, at least it works for me:

```
[Deployment]    
  InstallScope=user|machine

[Batman.dll]
  file-win32-x86=thiscab
  clsid={2C10EC82-2BF3-4ED5-8AFC-E5146C672B3D}
  FileVersion=1,0,0,1
  RegisterServer=yes
  RedirectToHKCU=yes
```

[Non-Admin ActiveX Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd433049%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, when I have modified my inf, when I log in as non-admin and try to access the page that loads ActiveX, I receive a prompt if I want to install it for machine or for current user. Even if I choose to install it for the current user, the ActiveX is not loaded. I also cannot find it on HD or registry... Do you think there is a need to modify rgs file or any addition needed in the HTML page?

Thanks

Comment: I think the cause is not in “Non-admin” feature. At least in my case INF file modifications were enough. I didn’t touch any other files. You can try to install it for all users, just for testing. Make sure that version numbers are identical (1,0,0,1 != 1.0.0.1), make sure you use right clsid in INF file.

Comment: I found it helpful to try manually registering my DLL via command line e.g:
regsvr32 <dll>
this reveals whether registration by itself is working or not.